# How to loop a list of item in 1 column and make a second column when it reach a limit

Tags: php

Ok, im sorry if this is a dumb question, i have spent many hours in google, but i can't find anything maybe because i dont know the correct keyword.

Si i need to ceate a list like this :

Some Title:

item 1            item 6

item 2            item 7

item 3            item 8

item 4

item 5

I need to looping a array of data then make it 2 column when it has reach it's limit, so that would be the same result as the template.

i would love to show a detail image, but i dont have enough reputation to do it. So hope you can understand.

plese help me if you know the solution.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_chunk()` & possibly `array_map()` (depending on how your really want it) can be your friends:

```
php > $array = range(1,8);
php > $chunked = array_chunk($array,5);
php > var_dump($chunked);
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(5) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(2)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
    [3] =>
    int(4)
    [4] =>
    int(5)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(6)
    [1] =>
    int(7)
    [2] =>
    int(8)
  }
}
php > array_unshift($chunked,NULL);
php > var_dump(call_user_func_array('array_map',$chunked));
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(6)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(2)
    [1] =>
    int(7)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(3)
    [1] =>
    int(8)
  }
  [3] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(4)
    [1] =>
    NULL
  }
  [4] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(5)
    [1] =>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your items in an array with a continuous numeric index starting at `0`, if you don't have this already you can achieve this with `array_values($array)`.

```
// assuming $array is set with your input array
$limit = 5; // set the row limit here
$count = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++)
{
    for ($e = 0; $e < $count; $e += $limit)
    {
        if (isset($array[$e]))
            echo $array[$e] . "\t";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```